# Unknown column for calculate field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having this problem in a complex query. This is the simplificated version:

```
SELECT sin(3.14) as s from my_table where s < 1
```

> Error:
>       #1054 - Unknown column 's' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HAVING` will SAVE You

```
SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$lat."*pi()/180)) *sin((latitud*pi()/180))
+cos((".$lat."*pi()/180)) 
* cos((latitud*pi()/180)) 
* cos(((".$lng."- longitud)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())
*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance 
FROM pois_data,pois_cat 
WHERE pois_data.idtipo=pois_cat.id AND latitud IS NOT NULL 

HAVING distance <1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sin(3.14) as s from my_table where sin(3.14) < 1;
```

Comment: Yes the standard requires that. Might `SELECT @s = sin(3.14) FROM my_table WHERE @s < 1` do? (Never seen.)

Comment: My field is too long, is there another way? This is the query: SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$lat."*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitud`*pi()/180))+cos((".$lat."*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitud`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$lng."- `longitud`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM pois_data,pois_cat WHERE pois_data.idtipo=pois_cat.id  AND latitud IS NOT NULL ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 50

Answer (score 1):

Create a VIEW on that table, with that expression as column.

```
CREATE VIEW vw
SELECT sin(3.14) AS s FROM my_table;

SELECT * FROM vw WHERE s < 1;
```

---

Or create a virtual column in the table itself.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    ...,
    s VIRTUAL FLOAT AS (sin(3.14))
);
```